# babel is not using .babelrc. Why?

Tags: babeljs

I am trying to learn babel. I got the babel-core module working, but I am trying to use `.babelrc` and it's not doing anything.

Here's my `.babelrc` file.

```js
{
    "plugins":["transform-es3-property-literals"]
}
```

And here's my code:

```js
var babel = require("babel-core");

var js = `var x = { catch: 4, bar: 7 };`;

var notUsingBabelRc = babel.transform(js,{
    plugins: ["transform-es3-property-literals"]
}).code;

var usingBabelRc = babel.transform(js).code

console.log(notUsingBabelRc == usingBabelRc);
//false, but should be true. Adding plugins as an option transforms the code.

console.log(usingBabelRc == js);
//true, but should be false. The code is not changed from its original form.
```

I have the `.babelrc` file in the root directory of the project. I also have my script file called `using_babelrc.js` a the root directory of the project.

Then I call `node using_babelrc` and I get `false true` even though I expect `true false`.

What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: I wrote with text "I have the babelrc file at the same level as the node script which is called using_babelrc.js". The post doesn't need the image, it's just to show in case I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform` function also needs the `filename` option supplied to start looking for `.babelrc` files relative to that filename. In your case:

```
babel.transform(js, {filename: "using_babelrc.js"}).code;
```

will read the config file in the same folder as `using_babelrc.js`.

Comment: and it looks like it's not documented, so this might be a good opportunity to contribute to the babel docs

Comment: Amazing...how do so many people use babel without this being documented? Is everyone just "in the know" except for me?

Comment: You know what the weird thing is, I don't even have to put the name of the actual file for it to work. `filename: "jibberishaksjdfaks.js` works the same. But if I have an empty string for the filename or don't include it at all, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, it just needs a relative path to start looking for the config file. Related to your other comment, I'm currently trying to get familiar with the babel codebase myself that's how I found out about this.